# How to get value from Json

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I need to get the value(String or int) from a Json AdSpot which has a toJson(), I need to retrieve the field by key "ext" (it's also a Json), then retrieve field by key "isBanner" from the Json value of ext.

Here is the Json AdSpot:

```
AdSpot(OpenRTB::Impression && imp)
    : OpenRTB::Impression(std::move(imp))
{
}

void fromJson(const Json::Value & val);
Json::Value toJson() const;
```

I tried to use get, but don't know what to pass in the parameter for the default value.

Comment: [tag:json] isn't a [tag:c++] standard feature.

Comment: I am using jsoncpp parser

Answer (score 1):

You will find the answer from [jsoncpp documentation](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html)
From a Json::Value you can get it as a string using

> std::string   asString () const

or as a intger using

> Int   asInt () const

Then the JSON navigation in your question could be done with :

> ```
> Json::Value extValue = value["ext"];
> Json::Value isBannerValue = extValue["isBanner"];
> std::string isBanner = isBannerValue.asString();
> ```

If it cannot be cast it will raise an exception.